# Yandex Music API php

Tags: php

Как подключить в php api yandex музыки ?
Поделитесь готовыми примерами использования music yandex api в php.

P.S. Первый раз взялся за API

Comment: Когда первый раз берёшься - идёт читать маны. Или гуглить, тут решают конкретные проблемы.

Comment: А у них разве есть api для музыки? Везде народ в статьях велосипеды пишет. Только что-то на js присутствует https://tech.yandex.ru/audio/jsapi/

Answer (score 3):

вставить код

```html
<script src="https://music.yandex.ru/api/audio/dist/index.min.js" type="javascript">
</script>
```

и выполнять действия следуя этой странице
https://tech.yandex.ru/audio/jsapi/doc/dg/concepts/load-docpage/